# rails 4 wicked pdf missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I have used wicked pdf gem for html to pdf generate in rails 4.It doesn't work for me and It throw error like this **ActionView::MissingTemplate at /events/calendar_month_print.pdf
Missing template events/calendar_month_print.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :rabl, :rxls, :"xls.rxls", :jbuilder]}. Searched in:** and i also created calendar_month_print.html.erb file in my app.I don't know where i'm missing.

My gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

My Controller file

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "monthly_events.pdf",:template => "events/calendar_month_print.html.erb"
    end
  end
```

My view file

```
  <%= button_to "Print as pdf", calendar_month_print_events_path(format: "pdf"), :class => "btn btn-primary button monthly_print pull-right",:method => :get,target: '_blank'  %>
```

My config/initializers/mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

My config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

```
WickedPdf.config = {
#:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
#:layout => "pdf.html",
:exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

Comment: Do you have file named `calendar_month_print.html.erb`?

Comment: Yes the file named calendar_month_print.html.erb.

Comment: Did it inside `app/views/events`?

Comment: sorry friend this is my fault.I moved that file to within app/views/events.Now working fine.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you give `render :pdf => "monthly_events.pdf",:template => "events/calendar_month_print.html.erb"`, Rails expects a file named `calendar_month_print.html.erb` in `app/views/events`. If you placed it somewhere else, then move it to `app/views/events`